# Solving $dy/dt = k(A-y)$ (phrased as rate of change probelm)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**The Problem**

The rate at which temperature decreases in a house is proportional to the difference between the current house-temperature and the temperature outside.

It's -10 degrees outside, at the start it's 20 degrees inside the house and after an hour it's 17 degrees. After how long is it minus degrees inside?

**My solution (attempt)**

We know that

$$dy/dt = k(y+10) \\ y(0) = 20 \\ y(1) = 17$$

We do a variable substitution $u(t) = y(t) + 10$ and we now have

$$ du/dt = ku \\ u(0) = 30 \\ u(1) = 27$$

A solution to the equation is $u(t) = e^{kt} + A$

$$u(0) = 30 \rightarrow e^{0k}+A =  1+A = 30 \rightarrow A = 29$$
$$u(1) = 27 \rightarrow e^k + 29 = 27 \rightarrow k = ln(-2) \rightarrow Undefined$$

And that's where I'm stuck. Am I supposed to re-write the difference $y+10$ to something else?

Comment: MathJax works for titles. Please use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close to the solution

$$dy/dt = k(y+10) \,; y(0) = 20 \,; y(1) = 17$$
$$y'=k(y+10) \implies \int \frac {dy}{y+10}=\int kdx=kx+C$$
$$\ln(y+10)=kx+C$$
$$y=e^{kx+c}-10$$
$$\boxed {y=Ce^{kx}-10}$$

Use the initial conditions to calculate k and C

$$C=30 \text{ , and } k=\ln(\frac 9 {10})$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Check if your proposed solution satisfied $u'(t) = k\, u(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the change of variable u= y+ 10 then the differential equation becomes du/dt= ku.  However, the general solution to that differential equation is NOT "$u(t)= e^{kt}+ A$".  You can see that by putting that u into the equation- with $u= e^{ky}+ A$, $du/dt= ke^{kt}$ which is NOT $ku= ke^{kt}+ kA$.

Instead the general solution is $u(t)= Ae^{kt}$.  That way, $du/dt= kAe^{kt}$ which **is** equal to $ku$.

What I would have expected you to do is write the equation as $du/u= kdt$.  Integrating both sides gives $ln(u)= kt+ C$ so that, taking the exponential of both sides $u= e^{kt+ C}= e^Ce^{kt}= De^{kt}$ where $D= e^C$.  (I am using "D" rather than "A" because you already have a "A" in the problem.)

With $u= y+ 10$, $y= u- 10= De^{kt}- 10$.